# SSRS Optional parameter with empty field

Tags: reporting-services

I need to run the report, without selecting anything,  with parameter field blank, and be able to view all the data.
the problem is that it necessarily asks me to enter a value (all or multi values).

Who can help me?

[image: 1]

Comment: I think you can set 'Allow NULL' or 'Allow Blanks' and set the default value for the parameter to null or blank.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work, it always asks me to enter a value, instead I want to be able to view all the data without selecting anything, just pressing the 'view' button

Comment: It should work if the default values are set, I've tested it. I will add a simple answer to demonstrate

Answer (score 0):

If you make sure that you do the following...

1. Set the parameter to "Allow blank value" and/or "Allow null value" depending on what datatype it is.
2. Set the default value to Blank (`=""`) if applicable
3. If you have a list of available values set, make sure the default value is included.

---

The following example uses sample data from sample database and contains just a list of company names and their ID's.

The main dataset query filters the data based on 2 parameters (one is text the other id numeric to show different scenarios)

This is the dataset query

```
  SELECT  CustomerID, CompanyName 
    FROM [AdventureWorksLT2019].[SalesLT].[Customer2] 
    WHERE CompanyName LIKE '%' + @pSearch + '%'
and CustomerID > ISNULL(@pID, 0)
    ORDER by CompanyName
```

The report design looks like this with 2 parameters defined

[image]

The first parameter is text and has "Allow blanks values" checked, the Default value is set to an expression `=""`

[image]

The second parameter is an integer, This time we have set "Allow null value" on but we have **not** set a default value.

[image]

### **Note:** Neither parameter has any available values set...

When the report is run I get the following results without pressing anything.

[image]

Only if I manually set any of the parameters do I need to press View Report, but when the report first runs, there is no need to click anything.

---

If the above does not help, then show how the parameter(s) are setup up, what types they are, what the available values are and what the default values are.